# In a noiseless environment, how accurate do today's transmitters send EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-engineering

Suppose that there is no external noise in the environment. How accurate are today's TEM wave transmitters in such a case?

So if we want to send $200\cos(1000\pi t)$, can transmitters send exactly this wave for $t>0$ where $t_0 = 0$ is the time of first transmission?

If not, are there any bounds for errors of transmissions?

Comment: You're wondering about state of the art, which is essentially engineering. Scientifically you're looking at the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, `ΔEΔt > ħ`. E would the photon's energy, which of course is `ħω` so `ΔωΔt > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is subtle point I would like to make; for the transmitter to send $200\cos(1000\pi t)$, the transmitter would need to exist for all time.

If the transmission starts at $t = 0$ and ends at $t = t_f$, the *ideal* transmitter would transmit

$$200\cos(1000\pi t)\left[u(t) - u(t - t_f)\right]$$

where $u(t)$ is the [unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

However, this is impossible since this would require the transmitter to have infinite bandwidth.

A more realistic model would be to replace the step with

$$u(t) \rightarrow (1 - e^{-t/\tau})u(t)$$

which is the step response of a 1st order low pass filter.

In addition, any physical transmitter has at least [phase noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_noise) and I suspect a lower limit on that is set by the [operating temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).